# Clarification regarding the notion of Ribbons given in Wikipedia

Tags: differential-geometry

I came across the following description in the Wikipedia article on Frenet-Serret formulas. I will just reproduce the relevant bit here.

> A Frenet ribbon along a curve C is the surface traced out by sweeping the line segment $ [−\bf{N,N} ]$ generated by the unit normal $\bf{N}$ along the curve. Geometrically, a ribbon is a piece of the envelope of the osculating planes of the curve. Symbolically, the ribbon R has the following parametrization:
>
> $$R(s,t) = C(s)+ t\mathbf{N},\quad -1\le t\le 1.$$
>   In particular, the binormal $\mathbf{B}$ is a unit vector normal to the ribbon. Moreover, the ribbon is a ruled surface whose reguli are the line segments spanned by $\mathbf{N}$.
>   The Gauss curvature of a Frenet ribbon vanishes, and so it is a developable surface.
>
> Geometrically, it is possible to "roll" a plane along the ribbon without slipping or twisting so that the regulus always remains within the plane. The ribbon then traces out a ribbon in the plane (possibly with multiple sheets). The curve C also traces out a curve $C_P$ in the plane, whose curvature is given in terms of the curvature and torsion of C by
>
> $$\kappa_P(s) = \pm\sqrt{\kappa(s)^2+\tau(s)^2}.$$
>   This fact gives a general procedure for constructing any Frenet ribbon.

My interest is in the last paragraph about rolling a plane and the relation between $\kappa_P$ and $\kappa, \tau$ of C. That square root quantity is the norm of the Darboux vector, but how do I extract that relation? Any references on the concept of ribbons as described here are also most welcome as I have never encountered them before in any Differential Geometry book I have used.

Comment: My recollection is that Shlomo Sternberg's text "Curvature in Mathematics and Physics" has an extensive discussion of ribbons in chapter 1.  I don't have the text with me at the moment, but I will try to confirm this later.  

I believe  that the pdf of this text is freely available at his website.  The text was also recently published as a Dover textbook and is a tremendous value at the price of $10-$15.  While the book is not one focused on the geometry of curves and surfaces in three-space, it is still a wonderful resource (especially at the price).

Comment: @THW. Thanks a lot for that reference. Indeed I just saw that book is put up on his website and have downloaded it. Will go through it.